# argument for using nAGQ=0 in glmer (lme4)

Tags: r, lme4

I am fitting a generalized linear mixed model using the glmer function from the package lme4. As I have 200 individuals and want to do cross validation, I have to run a model 200 times. I wanted to use nAGQ=1 for my cross validation, but because it take a looong time per model, the cross validation would take about a week - which I dont have the time to wait for. Therefore I have tried using nAGQ=0 as I have read it is faster, and I see that the estimates are very much like those from the model with nAGQ=1. However, I dont know how to explain what happens now that I am not using Lagrange approximation. What happens with the integral in the theory? I have looked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77313/why-cant-i-match-lmer-for-family-binomial/79826#79826.

It would also be very nice, if someone has a reference to the explanation of nAGQ=0 that I could refer to in my project.

Comment: Why do you have to run it 200 times to cross-validate? I don't understand the connection you're making between the number of individuals and the number of folds used in cross-validation. Couldn't you do, say, five-fold cross validation using training and test sets that all include observations from all 200 individuals?

Comment: I wouldn't use `nAGQ=0` in production unless you've reasonably carefully verified that the answers are close enough (for your purposes) between `nAGQ=0` and `nAGQ=1`, especially if you're being careful enough to do CV.  I agree with @ulfelder's comments above; I would also look at other possibilities like parallelizing the cross-validation process across multiple cores/processors on the same machine ...

Comment: this is cross-posted on CrossValidated as http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163211/argument-for-using-nagq-0-in-glmer-lme4 . Cross-posting is deprecated on StackExchange (e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu )Could you please pick whichever one you think is *less* appropriate and delete it ...

Comment: Sorry. How can I delete the other question? I cant seem to find a delete button.

Comment: I need to be more clear. I am running 200 model because I take each individual out, run the model on the others and predict the values of the particular individual as if it had been a new individual. My advisor told me to use this method, so I'll speak to him about it. Can you tell me what the difference between nAGQ=1 and nAGQ=0 is? I.e. what does nAGQ=1 do that nAGQ==0 doesnt do?